# onmouseover change img not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small piece of code and have implemented the onmouseover for the img tag, but nothing seems to be working.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images\video-1.png" class="video" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images\news-1.png" class="news" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images\logo-4.png" class="home" style="width:80px;height:80px;"
               onmouseover="this.src='images\logo-4-hover.png';"
               onmouseout="this.src='images\logo-4.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images\games-1.png" class="games" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images\music-1.png" class="music" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thank You

Comment: Do the rest of the images load? If so, have you confirmed that the logo-4-hover.png is in the same folder?

Comment: all images load, and the image is in the  same folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change all the backslashes to forward slashes. Backslashes in JavaScript are special characters.

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/video-1.png" class="video" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news-1.png" class="news" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo-4.png" class="home" style="width:80px;height:80px;"onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-4-hover.png';"
     onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-4.png';"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/games-1.png" class="games" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/music-1.png" class="music" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```